# How can users help migrate questions from MSE to MSO

Tags: discussion, flags, migration, mso-mse-split

I'm happy the split has been done, but I feel a bit troubled by the fact that so far, all questions end up on MSE unless explicitly migrated to MSO. The [announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/?cb=1) states that

> We’re in the process of migrating quite a few Stack Overflow specific discussions that are still relevant and unresolved, to help to show the kind of topics that belong on the new MSO.

Furthermore, [the status of the split](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250024/1468366) writes:

> However, we're starting to 'cherry pick' a few, sending them over manually, which will continue on and off today. I expect to do the bulk of sending things back over on Friday, April 18, as things should be settled and stable by then.

My question is, what shall I do with those questions which still are on MSE after this date, even though MSO would be the correct place for them. Particularly questions which I have a personal interest in, e.g. because I asked them myself? **Can I somehow nominate them for bulk migration?** Perhaps by making sure they contain a useful tag, like those [summarized by Gilles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228903/188688)? Or by flagging them for moderator attention? A request to [establish a migration flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229941/188688) was [declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229941/replace-programming-questions-are-off-topic-close-reason-with-migrate-to-meta#comment755284_229941) in a comment, but I'm not sure that's the last word, and it would seem an obvious solution to me.

I did some research, and found different answers in different places. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250175/1468366) Shog9 suggests flagging them, but at the same time warns against [flagging them all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229787/188688). But I'm not sure whether the advice against flagging things still applies after the bulk migration has been done. In the long run, MSO questions placed on MSE don't make a sense, so something should be done about them. Question is, what and when.