# Is flagging a question the appropriate way to request a migration?

Tags: support, migration

With the addition of Meta Stack Exchange, I noticed a few of my questions that hadn't yet been migrated. No biggie, I'm sure they would be gotten to in time.

In the meanwhile, though, is it still appropriate to flag a question, if it only needs to be migrated? I ask only because the language in the flagging dialogue is solely about *closing* the question:

[image]

Comment: Until there is a migration close option, I see no other way to tell someone that you want to migrate it. However, just be mindful of the "don't migrate crap" rule.

Comment: I doubt you'd use that flag - since presumably it'll just go to the close vote queue, which won't help with migration. It'd need a moderator flag - but I'm not sure if thats appropriate or not so still a good question.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251244/how-can-users-help-migrate-questions-from-mse-to-mso and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250976/migrations-are-now-in-progress: *"After I've spent a couple of days at this, you're welcome to go flag things that weren't sent over that are: Still relevant, preferably undecided and actionable - people should have something to do other than say "Oh, that's nice" once it's migrated; Not in the FAQ or FAQ-proposed family (not yet certain where we're going with that); Extremely specific to Stack Overflow itself"*